# Jpa Add foreign key of user_group to entity MessageRecipient

Tags: jpa

I have four entities Message, User, Group, MessageRecipient.  I have added a `@ManyToMany` user in Group entity, jpa automatically creates extra table user_group, now I want this user group to have its own id so I can add this as a foreign key to MessageRecipient Entity

Basically, this image is what I am trying to achieve with JPA  [image: the image gives an idea what I want to realize with JPA]
[image: the main entities]

Currently, I have this

```
@Entity
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> users;

    private boolean isActive;

    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;

}

@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String subject;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "creatorId")
    private User user;

    private String messageBody;

    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;

    private Integer parentMessageId;

    private LocalDateTime expiryDate;

    private Integer isReminder;

    private LocalDateTime nextRemindDate;

    private Integer remindFrequencyId;

}

@Entity
public class MessageRecipient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "recipient_Id")
    private User user;


    //this is where i should have FK of the user_group table 
    private Integer recipient_group_id;

    @Column(name = "message_id")
    private Message message;

    private boolean isRead;

}
```

To solve it by creating another entity i did

```
public class UserGroup {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;


private User user;

private Group group;

}
```

What happens with the annotation `@ManyToMany` user in the Group Entity and the automatic creation of user_group as a result of that

Comment: my issue is normally jpa creates user_group automatically , @K.Nicholas so what happens if i create it myself and still use the annotations , will i have two user group entities in my database ?

Comment: @K.Nicholas ok i will check that , can you check my answer to see if it is correct , i just posted a solution

Comment: ok i will read the link you sent to understand the issue then understand Embeddable composite key @K.Nicholas

Answer (score 1):

My solution is this 
Entity

```
  @Entity
public class MessageRecipient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "recipient_Id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "recipient_group_id")//this is where i should have FK of the user_group table
    private UserGroup userGroup;

    @Column(name = "message_id")
    private Message message;

    private boolean isRead;
}


    @Entity
    public class Group {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        private String name;

        @ManyToMany
        private Set<User> users;

        private boolean isActive;

        private LocalDateTime dateCreated;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Message {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        private String subject;

        @ManyToOne
        @Column(name = "creatorId")
        private User user;
    }
```